# Запятые при обороте "и без того"

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно расставить запятые: "Наше(?) и без того хорошее настроение"?

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: Наше **и без того** хорошее настроение.

Оборот **и без того**  часто встречается в речи, обычно примыкает к глаголу или прилагательному и не обособляется, например:

― Это резко ухудшит наше **и без того** скверное положение, ― угрюмо кивнул Торосов. [Дмитрий Биленкин. 1982]  Происходящее **и без того** кажется ему нереальным, неправдоподобным, снотворческим. [Алексей Слаповский. Гибель гитариста (1994-1995)]

Но сочетание может относиться к обособленному обороту: Но в эту секунду он, **и без того высокий и прямой**, выпрямился ещё пуще.